# Next.js SSR - Specify what components render on the server

Tags: next.js

I'm using Next.js's SSR to serve pages at run-time; it's a somewhat heavy page, and for various reasons I can't go with full-on static generation. For most of the page, I'm fine with it being lazy loaded or hydrated whenever; but for some of the above-the-fold content, I'd like to ensure Next.js is rendering it server-side to avoid long wait times before the largest contentful paint.

Is there a way to get Next to pre-render some component HTML without having to wait for client-side JS execution?

Thanks!

Comment: _"pre-render some component HTML without having to wait for client-side JS execution"_ - If you mean without waiting for hydration to occur then that's not possible. React has to hydrate the page that has been pre-rendered on the server.

Comment: I think my conception of what "pre-rendered" meant was incorrect; I expected Next to spit out HTML, but it seems like what it really does is just spit out all the relevant JSON to hydrate the page. Kind of a misnomer; it's not really rendering anything.